# How can I seq_along an object of type response (httr package)

Tags: r, httr

I have a list that contains 4 objects of type Response, as in an API response:

```
Response [https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search?&operation= etc. etc.]

Date: 2018-06-04 12:27
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Size: 45 kB
```

Suppose the list is called `holle`, I can access the contents and reassign them to another list, `revs`, as follows:

```
library(httr)
library(rlist)

revs[[1]] <- content(holle[[1]])$elementList
```

This works perfectly fine and all is well. However, I would like to seq_along each element and access the contents. When I write a for/seq_along, I get this error message:

```
for (i in seq_along(content(holle)$elementList)){

  revs[[i]] <- content(holle[[i]])$elementList

}

"Error in content(holle) : is.response(x) is not TRUE".
```

Why?

Comment: I think you just want `for (i in seq_along(holle)) {` since you are using the `i` index on `holle[[i]]` directly.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't realised I has asking for $elementList twice. Thank you!